# Can't DeserializeObject Json Xamarin

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

I'm having trouble deserializing Json in xamarin.

I'm getting this issue:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type RadioApp.Model.Data. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'data', line 1, position 8.
```

Now, This is the class I'm using:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RadioApp.Model
{
    public class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public DJData DjData { get; set; }
    }


    public class DJData
    {
        [JsonProperty("listeners")]
        public int Listeners { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("song")]
        public string Song { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("live_dj")]
        public string DJ { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("song_history")]
        public SongHistory[] song_history { get; set; }
    }


    public class SongHistory
    {
        public int playedat { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    }

    public class Metadata
    {
        public string tit2 { get; set; }
    }



}
```

Here is the string I get:

```
[0:] Result: {"data":{"listeners":78,"song":"Shawn Wasabi - OTTER POP (ft. Hollis)","live_dj":"Tyeisha","mini_rooster":[],"song_history":[{"playedat":1508958065,"title":"Shawn Wasabi - OTTER POP (ft. Hollis)","metadata":{"tit2":"Shawn Wasabi - OTTER POP (ft. Hollis)"}},{"playedat":1508957837,"title":"Katy Perry Ft. Nicki Minaj - Swish Swish","metadata":{"tit2":"Katy Perry Ft. Nicki Minaj - Swish Swish"}},{"playedat":1508957710,"title":"HOUSE OF GOLDTWENTY ONE PILOTS","metadata":{"tit2":"HOUSE OF GOLDTWENTY ONE PILOTS"}},{"playedat":1508957363,"title":"K.Flay - High Enough","metadata":{"tit2":"K.Flay - High Enough"}},{"playedat":1508957177,"title":"Melanie Martinez - Dollhouse (Jai Wolf Remix)","metadata":{"tit2":"Melanie Martinez - Dollhouse (Jai Wolf Remix)"}},{"playedat":1508956744,"title":"Calvin Harris Ft. Pharrell Williams, Katy Perry & Big Sean - Feels","metadata":{"tit2":"Calvin Harris Ft. Pharrell Williams, Katy Perry & Big Sean - Feels"}},{"playedat":1508956532,"title":"Major Lazer, Travis Scott, Camila Cabello, Quavo - Know No Better (feat. Quavo)","metadata":{"tit2":"Major Lazer, Travis Scott, Camila Cabello, Quavo - Know No Better (feat. Quavo)"}},{"playedat":1508956039,"title":"Darren Styles - Us Against The World (Da Tweekaz Remix)","metadata":{"tit2":"Darren Styles - Us Against The World (Da Tweekaz Remix)"}},{"playedat":1508955843,"title":"Mullaha - For You Only","metadata":{"tit2":"Mullaha - For You Only"}},{"playedat":1508955498,"title":"The Script - Rain","metadata":{"tit2":"The Script - Rain"}}]}}
```

have no idea what is going wrong here, I have used the same code (except there only was one class per file), in multiple projects and it worked like a charm, could someone explain me what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message is indicating, try adding a default constructor to the class in question:

```
 public class Data
 {
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public DJData DjData { get; set; }

    public Data() {}
 }
```

Also check what [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938529/jsonserializationexception-unable-to-find-a-constructor-on-xamarin-android) is suggesting:

> In the 'Android options' tab of the project properties, there is a
>   'linker' tab. Is the selected option in the 'Linking' dropdown "Sdk
>   Assemblies only" or is it "Sdk and user assemblies"?
>
> If it is the latter, the parameterless constructor is skipped when
>   linking, because no use is detected. So change it to "Sdk Assemblies
>   only".

Comment: I tried that too, but that didn't solve the issue... Also tried the edit you made with the SDK Assembly.